# Python: My code repeats itself after it should have finished

Tags: python

I am writing a rock, paper, scissors game in Python but my code doesn't work as it should. I'm new to Python so please let me know if my code isn't formatted corectly. The game runs fine, assuming you enter one of the already existing answers. However, if you enter one that is different, the code seems to loop randomly after the 'end()' function is executed.

Here is my code:

```
# imports needed files
from random import randint
import time
# creates a function that ends the game
def end(cpuScore,playerScore):
    time.sleep(1)
    cont = input("Would you like to play again? (y or n)\n")
    if cont=="y":
        time.sleep(1)
        start()
    else:
        print("Well... That's a bit rude.")
# creates a function to play the game
def rps(cpuScore,playerScore,num):
    # loops code 3 times (unless 'num' is different)
    for x in range(num):
        num-=1
        # creates options
        options = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
        # picks a random choice for cpu
        cpu = options[randint(0,2)]
        # asks the player to choose
        player = input("rock, paper or scissors?\n")
        # why not gun?
        if player=="gun":
            result = "w"
        elif player==cpu:
            result = "d"
        elif player=="rock":
            if cpu=="paper":
                result = "l"
            if cpu=="scissors":
                result = "w"
        elif player=="paper":
            if cpu=="scissors":
                result = "l"
            if cpu=="rock":
                result = "w"
        elif player=="scissors":
            if cpu=="rock":
                result = "l"
            if cpu=="paper":
                result = "w"
        # if they choose something other than rock, paper, scissors or gun
        else:
            print("That's an invalid input!")
            # adds one to num so that this round is not counted as one of the 3
            num+=1
            # plays the game again with the amount of rounds remaining
            rps(cpuScore,playerScore,num)

        # tells the player how they did
        if result=="w":
            playerScore+=1
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Fine! You win! Your silly " + player + " beat my " + cpu + "!!!")
        if result=="l":
            cpuScore+=1
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Ha! Sucker!! My epic " + cpu + " smashed your measly " + player + "!!!")
        if result=="d":
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Ah! We drew by both choosing %s! Like they say, great minds think alike!" % cpu)
        # announces the scores
        print("You are on %s and the computer is on %s!" % (playerScore,cpuScore))
    # ends the game after 3 rounds
    end(cpuScore,playerScore)
# creates the funtion that sets the variables and starts the game
def start():
    result=""
    cont=""
    cpuScore=0
    playerScore=0
    rps(cpuScore,playerScore,3)
# begins the game
start()
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code here. You can use other links for auxilliar files which are not necessary important but needed to know how the program works

Comment: Don't use pastebin, embed the code (formatted) in the question, please.  It means add four space in front of every line.

Comment: OK I'll add it now

Comment: Can you also please use a test-case ? The code looks fine as it is.

Comment: Code runs fine for me....what exactly is your problem?

Comment: If you enter a choice that is not one of the designated choices, the code seems to loop randomly after the `end()` function is executed. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Basically your `rps` function loops `num` times, with `num = 3` initially.  If the user enters an incorrect input, you call back the function, *which starts the whole process again*, in a new context, for `num+1` times.

Thus if you answer wrong the first time you have at least six games to play: four new added and the two initial ones you didn't try to play.

My advice try first to do a program that do one and only one iteration of the rock-paper-scissor game.  Adding more iteration is a simple fact of adding a global loop.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responce. What you have described is an issue, but I noticed it earlier on, and added `num-=1` at the start of `rps`. I have already done a program that runs once and it worked but I wanted to try a new challenge.

Comment: num-=1 will not solve the recursive call, though it will be less dramatic.  If you answer wrong the first time, you have four games to play.  two for the recursive call and the two in the initial loop you didn't try to play.  For looping, keep the loop away from you run-only once-code, like this `while True: play_a_game()`.  It's okay if you have several functions.